# Putting all lines that match specific pattern at the end of the file

Tags: bash

I have number of .txt files that look like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNN
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Is it possible to give a command in bash that all the lines that start with N should end up at the end of the file. So I am expecting something like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

..and to do it on all files from one folder.

Comment: The only way I can think to do that is to separate the matching and non-matching lines into two temporary files - and then concatenate them back with the name of the original file

Comment: Thnaks man for Your suggestion! At the bottom is the answer if You encounter similar problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{
    grep -v '^N' file.txt
    grep '^N' file.txt
} > file.txt.temp
mv file.txt.temp file.txt
```

This works by matching all lines that do not start with 'N' (`grep -v '^N'`) then matching all lines that do start with 'N' (`grep '^N'`), outputting into a temporary file, then replacing the original with the temp file.

Then if you wanted to use this on all *.txt files in a directory:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    {
        grep -v '^N' "$f"
        grep '^N' "$f"
    } > "$f".temp
    mv "$f".temp "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options using `awk`

First, the KISS version - using a couple of temporary files `a` and `b`:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  awk '/^N/ {print > "b"; next} {print > "a"}' "$f"
  cat a b > "$f"
done
```

---

*Just because. . .*

What you really want to do is an in-place sort with a custom sort order (lines starting with `N` after everything else, then original order), for example in GNU `awk`:

```
function mycmp(ia, a, ib, b) {
  x = substr(a,1,1) == "N"
  y = substr(b,1,1) == "N"
  if (x && !y) return 1
  else if (!x && y) return -1
  else return ia - ib
}

{a[FNR] = $0}

ENDFILE {
  for (i in a) print a[i]
}
```

Newer versions of `gawk` provide an in-place extension - borrowing the reference implementation from [16.7.4 Enabling In-Place File Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)
we can put it all together as a gawk script, `Nsort.awk` say:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

@load "inplace"

function mycmp(ia, a, ib, b) {
  x = substr(a,1,1) == "N"
  y = substr(b,1,1) == "N"
  if (x && !y) return 1
  else if (!x && y) return -1
  else return ia - ib
}

BEGIN {
  inplace = 1
  INPLACE_SUFFIX = ".bak"
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "mycmp"
}

BEGINFILE {
    if (_inplace_filename != "")
        inplace_end(_inplace_filename, INPLACE_SUFFIX)
    if (inplace)
        inplace_begin(_inplace_filename = FILENAME, INPLACE_SUFFIX)
    else
        _inplace_filename = ""
}

{a[FNR] = $0}

ENDFILE {
  for (i in a) print a[i]
}

END {
    if (_inplace_filename != "")
        inplace_end(_inplace_filename, INPLACE_SUFFIX)
}
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x Nsort.awk` and run it as

```
./Nsort.awk *.txt
```

Comment: This is also working, thank You for these multiple choices! Best

Answer (score 0):

### GNU awk (version 4.1.0 and later)

```
awk -i inplace '/^N/{ printlast = printlast $0 RS ; next } { print $0 } ENDFILE { printf "%s",printlast ; printlast="" }' file1 file2 file3
```

1. Use `-i inplace` to replace the original file with the reordered file.  **CAUTION: This will overwrite files that are set read-only.**
2. If a line starts with `N`, append the line to the buffer `printlast`.
3. Otherwise, print the line.
4. At the end of the file, print the buffer `printlast`, then reset it for the next file.
5. Specify as many input files as you want (eg, `a.txt b.txt c.txt` or `*.txt`).

Replace `-i inplace` with `-i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=".bak"` to keep a copy of each original file.  In this example, the backup copy filenames will all end in `.bak`.

### Other versions of awk

If your version of `awk` can't edit files in place, and if you don't want to create temporary files, then you can pipe the output of `awk` through `sponge` (from the `moreutils` package):

```
ls -1 *.txt | \
while read file
do
    chmod +w "${file}"
    awk '/^N/{ printlast = printlast $0 RS ; next } { print $0 } ENDFILE { printf "%s",printlast }' "${file}" | \
    sponge "${file}"
done
```

You need to make the input files writable -- `chmod +w "${file}"` -- for `sponge` to modify them.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)! Use a glob, and `for` instead of `while`: `for file in *.txt`. This avoids problems with filenames that contain special characters like newlines.

Comment: @WJAndrea - The `while` structure has its own advantages, such as making it easier to do more preprocessing steps before passing the file list through the loop, or in reading the list of input files from another file by way of `cat` or `<`.  Besides, someone had already shown how to use `for`.